# How to add horizontal lines in kable and the bottom line being thicker and orange

Tags: r, kable

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(...1 = c("Catalunya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", 
"Demanda externa1", "Espanya", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", 
"Zona euro", "PIB", "Demanda interna1", "Demanda externa1", "PIB d'Alemanya", 
"PIB de França", "PIB d'Itàlia", "Internacional", "PIB de la UE-27", 
"PIB dels EUA", "PIB del Japó"), `2020` = c(NA, -11.9, -7.4, 
-4.5, NA, -11.2, -9, -2.2, NA, -6.1, -5.57, -0.53, -3.8, -7.5, 
-9, NA, -5.6, -2.2, -4.3), `2021` = c(NA, 6.2, 3.8, 2.4, NA, 
6.4, 5.9, 0.5, NA, 5.6, 4.24, 1.36, 3.2, 6.4, 8.3, NA, 5.7, 5.8, 
2.1), `2022` = c(NA, 5.5, 2.7, 2.8, NA, 5.5, 5.12183164381576, 
0.378168356184236, NA, 3.6, 3.76, -0.16, 1.8, 2.5, 3.7, NA, 3.5, 
1.9, 1.1), `1r 2023` = c(NA, 3.2, 1.1, 2.1, NA, 4.1, 1.3, 2.8, 
NA, 1.2, 0.63, 0.57, -0.2, 1, 2.1, NA, 1.1, 1.71772942152937, 
2), `2n 2023` = c(NA, 2.1, 1.2, 0.9, NA, 2, 2.2, -0.2, NA, 0.5, 
0.46, 0.04, 0.1, 1.1, 0.3, NA, 0.4, 2.38237207285343, 1.7), `3r 2023` = c(NA, 
2.1, NA, NA, NA, 1.8, 1.6, 0.2, NA, 0.1, NA, NA, -0.4, 0.7, 0, 
NA, 0.1, 3, 1.2)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I am creating a table in Markdown (to PDF), using this code:

```
options(knitr.kable.NA = "-")

p3_1[3,1] <- p3_1[7,1] <- p3_1[11,1] <- "$\\text{Demanda interna}^1$"
p3_1[4,1] <- p3_1[8,1] <- p3_1[12,1] <- "$\\text{Demanda externa}^1$"


kable(p3_1,
      align = "lrrrrrr",
      col.names = c("", names(p3_1[-1])),
      booktabs=TRUE,
      digits=1,
      format.args = list(big.mark="."),
      linesep = "" ,
      caption="Producte interior brut (\\% de variació interanual, llevat dels casos indicats)", escape = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("", "Any" = 3, "Trimestre" = 3), bold=T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("HOLD_position","scale_down"), bootstrap_options = c("condensed"), position="center") %>% 
  column_spec(1, bold=T, width="4cm") %>%
  column_spec(2:7, width="2cm") %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
  row_spec(c(1, 5, 9, 16), background="lightgray") %>%
  row_spec(19, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid;") %>%
  footnote(general="Idescat; Eurostat; INE; BEA; ESRI; Agència Estatal d'Administració Tributària.", general_title = "Font:", footnote_as_chunk = T,)  %>%
  footnote(general="$^{A}$Dada avançada. $^{1}$Contribució al creixement. $^{2}$Sèrie original corregida d'efectes de calendari. 
           $^{3}$En valors constants. Exclou estacions de servei.",  escape = F, general_title = "Nota:", threeparttable = TRUE, footnote_as_chunk = T,)
```

Which results in:

[image]

How can I add light grey lines to the whole table and the bottom line being thicker and orange?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible approach (updated to include editing of line thickness - partially).

This uses `kableExtra::kbl()` function which allows editing of table lines with LaTeX. Add LaTeX package `colortbl` to the yaml to access functions to change table line colours.

Line thicknesses:

Note line thickness is defined as line width in the `booktabs` package (for reasons explained in the  package - well worth a read).

If you want thicker lines between the rows, this can be achieved with the `linesep` argument, which would normally take a `hline` value, but hline does not have a width argument, so we can cheat and use `midrule` which does take a width argument.

I could not find a way to  change the thickness of the horizontal line below the column group header; There is no option to do this in kableExtra.

If you remove the column group headings then the toprule will take a width argument and the toprule will be thicker.

A quick look at the source code seems to suggest that the option for `cmidlines` are hardcoded in the `add_header_above` function so not accessible for editing in any way obvious to me - others with more understanding may propose a solution.

Super quick response from an issue raised at https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra has resolved the bug preventing editing of the toprule. Currently this is accessible from the development version of `kableExtra`; which can be installed with: `devtools::install_github("haozhu233/kableExtra")`

The answer is based on a minimal dataset which can be applied to your data.

So if you do not need to adjust the thickness of the column header rule (`cmidrule`) then this may work.

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
---

```{r}

library(kableExtra)

    kbl(mtcars[1:5, 1:4],
        caption="kable colour lines and vary thickness",
        booktabs = TRUE,
        vline = "",
        toprule = "\\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\\toprule[4pt]",
        midrule = "\\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\\midrule[3pt]",
        bottomrule = "\\arrayrulecolor{orange}\\bottomrule[5pt]",
        linesep = "\\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\\midrule[2pt]") |>
    add_header_above(c("", "Any" = 2, "Trimestre" = 2), bold = TRUE) |>
    column_spec(1, bold=TRUE, width="4cm") |>
    column_spec(2:5, width="2cm") |>
    row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)

```
````

[image]

Comment: And is it possible to make the lines thicker?

Comment: See edited answer with line thickness altered for bottomrule, linesep and midrule placement. KableExtra seems unable to allow editing of toprule or cmidrule where `add_header_above` is used.

Comment: The toprule customization issue was a bug that has been fixed.  The cmidrule customization is a feature request that hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @user2554330 many thanks for resolving the `topline` issue so promptly; this makes a real difference. Looking forward to seeing the update and hopefully the `cmidule` customization - have updated the answer. Really like the kableExtra package.